# Distribution country for beta testing in Google Play

Tags: google-play, beta-testing

For: Google Play Developer console

I have my app to distribute only on USA but I need to test the store version using the beta testing but if I'm outside of USA I can't install it, even if I´m a beta tester.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find a workable solution to this problem in the end?

Comment: Nope, Im using fabric for testing releases

Comment: Does that work for the users outside of the authorised territories on the play store?

Comment: @DavidWadge fabric is not related to Google Play, you create test users based on emails, no territories, but users should enable installs by unauthorized developers on settings... fabric.io

Answer (score 7):

*Edit (August 2018):*

It seems that is possible to do this now. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024

*Original answer:*

We have this problem also. We have an app that is available only in Spain, and we want to have beta testers in Italy to test the app before we make it available to all public. I've just asked this to the support guy on `https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/` (there is a chat that appears at the bottom).

**My question:**

The app is available only in Spain but we want to have beta testers in Italy. Is this possible?

**Support answer:**

The country distribution refers to the whole app, not individual tracks (like beta or production). As a result, it is not possible to beta test in one country whilst the production version is in another country.

**Conclusion:**

It seems that you need to make it available to that region before people living on that region can install it and beta-test it.

Comment: @Bataleon no idea. You could try to contact them and ask again. I did ask them through a chat that was available on the URL that I posted.

Comment: It now seems possible: `"In addition to the availability configured for production, you can customize country targeting for alpha and beta releases. By default, your alpha and beta releases match the country availability you've set up for production."` Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024

Comment: @Bataleon I've updated the answer, including your link. Thanks!